# Electromagnetic Induction Effect Affecting Musical Wall Clock

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, time, electromagnetic-induction

I have a battery-powered musical wall clock which plays the requisite number of musical chimes each time the hour strikes.

I have noticed for years that turning the lights on or off causes the chime volume to instantly increase/decrease in sync with the flip switching-It stays at the new volume after. Though I have to check the direction of the effect and whether flipping other electrical switches (e.g. fans) has the same effect.

Mine is a standard issue residence (240 V, 50 hz) with normal insulated walls etc. I assume it is an induction effect of some sort, but don't get how it works. I also don't have the circuit diagram for the clock :-/.

Any thoughts on a possible mechanism would be great. Been bugging me for years and I am too rusty on the electrical engineering to figure it out....

Thanks in advance,

(Okay it isn't working right now, but I think the directions are as I stated above.)

Edited according to the clarification suggested by Philip Wood.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For example, is it a battery that powers the clock? For how long a time is the loudness of the chimes affected?

Comment: I wonder if the clock has a user-adjustable volume control for the chimes. If so, the circuitry could well be quite sophisticated (not just a variable resistor!) and possibly susceptible to interference by a pulse of electromagnetic waves from a mains switch turned on or off. But this is very hand-wavy. Let's hope you get a better answer from someone on this site or the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange – if you try there.

Comment: Thanks..I will check later if it does-I think it does. Thanks for the tip. You are right E. Engg is probably the better forum for this. I will post it there later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you flip on the light switch, a surge of current suddenly flows out of the house mains and into the light assembly. This sudden surge causes the mains voltage to momentarily dip down and then spring back to normal levels.

The "dip down and spring back" is called a *glitch* or a *surge* and all the AC mains wiring in your house will serve as an antenna to broadcast the glitch as if it were a radio signal.

If another appliance nearby lacks sufficient *RF shielding* to block the radiated glitch from getting into its circuitry, then that circuitry can be upset or scrambled by the glitch and cause the appliance to malfunction.

Prudent design of appliances requires that they be able to withstand such *radiated electromagnetic interference* without ill effects, but the cheaper the appliance, the less likely it is to pass a radiated EMI test.

Comment: @PM2Ring OMG- RADIATED EMI!!!!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference Hey, Thanks a lot! I am looking up radiated emi and rf shielding. If I had the internal circuit diagram of the clock it would now be easier to pinpoint more exactly how the clock's volume control is affected, but at least this is a start. Huh..I suppose lots of devices have lousy rf shielding and it was only obvious with this one because there is such a clear read-out.

Comment: Keeping this as well: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/difference-between-conducted-EMI-radiated-EMI-electromagnetic-interference/